# How implicit conversion works for non-type template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, template-specialization

I guess (certain) implicit conversions apply when passing non-type template parameters. For example, there should be a conversion from `int` to `std::size_t` for expressions like `std::array<int, 7>`. However, consider the following code:

```
template <bool>
void f() {
    std::cout << "false\n";
}

template <>
void f<true>() {
    std::cout << "true\n";
}

int main() {
    f<1>();
    f<4>();
    f<0>();
}
```

I expect `int` to be implicitly converted to `bool` here. But the behaviors are different on VC, GCC, and clang.

On VC, `true`, `false`, and `false` are printed, which is really weird to me.

On GCC, `true`, `true`, and `false` are printed, which is what I expect.

While on clang, the code does not compile at all due to the statement `f<4>();`.

> candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for 1st template parameter

So, what does the standard say about this? What is the implicit conversion rule for non-type template parameters?

Comment: The VC behavior is at least clear: It's taking the LSB of the input integral type and using that as the boolean value. I still don't know which behavior is correct.

Comment: @MarkB Not really, `f<3>();` still prints `false`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the standard (§14.3.2/5):

> The following conversions are performed on each expression used as a non-type *template-argument*. If a
>   non-type *template-argument* cannot be converted to the type of the corresponding *template-parameter* then
>   the program is ill-formed.
>
> - For a non-type *template-parameter* of integral or enumeration type, conversions permitted in a converted constant expression (5.19) are applied.

In §5.19, we learn (emphasis mine):

> An *integral constant expression* is an expression of integral or unscoped enumeration type, implicitly converted
>   to a prvalue, where the converted expression is a core constant expression. ... A *converted constant expression* of
>   type `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to a prvalue of type T, where the converted expression is a core
>   constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only user-defined conversions, lvalue-to-rvalue
>   conversions (4.1), integral promotions (4.5), and integral conversions (4.7) **other than narrowing conversions
>   (8.5.4)**. *[ Note:* such expressions may be used in new expressions (5.3.4), as case expressions (6.4.2),
>   as enumerator initializers if the underlying type is fixed (7.2), as array bounds (8.3.4), and as integral or
>   enumeration non-type template arguments (14.3). *—end note ]*

So narrowing conversions (like converting `4` to `bool`) are explicitly disallowed for integral constant expressions, which are required in this case as a non-type template argument. That makes the call `f<4>()` ill-formed.

I believe Clang is correct in issuing an error, and GCC and VC are both nonconforming for not issuing any diagnostic.

[Update] This is [GCC Bug #57891](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57891), looks like it's currently unassigned.

Comment: Could you provide any reference to the standard about the conversion from `0` and `1` to `bool` not be narrowing?

Comment: OK, I seem to find it myself. _A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type._

Comment: I've filed a bug for VC++ [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2283106).